# Javascript Date.toString() formatting?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I have the following piece of script. It's a HTML5 slider with a date range. The slider is using a unix timestamp and I want to display the current selection in a readable format.

This is working fine but is outputting as "Wed May 16 2012 08:07:30 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)" despite me specifying the format as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Any ideas why it's not outputting in my format?

```
<input id="slider3" type="range" min="1337149800" max="1337160600"
  step="450" onchange="printValue('slider3','rangeValue3')"/>
<input id="rangeValue3" type="text" size="90"/>

<script>
function printValue(sliderID, textbox) {
  var x = document.getElementById(textbox);
  var y = document.getElementById(sliderID);

  var d1=new Date(y.value*1000);

  var newtimestamp = d1.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  x.value = newtimestamp;
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks Mat - I was able to put together a solution from the answers on that. I've edited the question with a solution.

Comment: Please put your answer in an answer instead of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript's `Date` object does not support that. There's plenty of libraries to do this for you.

Comment: @user1107685 Please do not add answers within questions. Just add your own answer instead.

Comment: If there are plenty of libraries then naming a few shouldn't have hurt you...

Comment: recent implementations of JavaScript/ECMAScript allow `Date.toString()` and other variants. libraries like Moment.js help with dates in general, as not all days have 24 hours etc. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685571/1875965